# Switching math & text fonts mid-document

Tags: fonts, mathpazo

I would like to use the fonts given by `cmbright` for part of my document, and the default CM fonts or perhaps `mathpazo` for another part.

What is the easiest, best way to do this? I have seen usually in other answers that changing math fonts can be a big ordeal. I am looking for a modern, clean approach to this (as much as possible). Thanks for your help!

Comment: The easiest way is to use `unicode-math` package to choose OpenType math fonts, but there are not as many OpenType fonts as old ones.

Comment: The main obstacle is not in changing fonts, because one can define math versions, but rather the fact that math font packages frequently change the symbol tables. And this is the case with `mathpazo`.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile your document using `xelatex`, you can easily define various fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
% XeLaTeX
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
‎
% Math ‎Font‎
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

% Fonts
\setmainfont{Arial}‎
\newfontfamily\cf{Courier New}‎

\begin{document}‎
\[‎
‎\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i
\]

Arial font. ‎
‎
\cf{Courier New font}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? It will be for sure helpful to make more clear the answer. `:)`

Comment: been provided !

Comment: @smh The question was also on how to switch math font. Please, add it to the example.

Comment: The question is about changing *math* and text fonts.